# ssms error while saving .sql file... " The operation cannot be completed"

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2008

I am using sql server management studio 2008. I have a .sql file of about 45 MB. When I make some change in this and try to save using Save Button or press Ctrl+S.... error occurs as:

> The operation cannot be completed

But when I installed SSMS, it was working properly, but after that 45 mb file operation it's not working properly. Also Object Explorer is not visible, even after selecting from menu>>view>>object explorer. I am using Windows 7 32 bit.

Comment: Can you check your windows event viewer and tell us what it says there?  And for some unsolicited advice: maybe a 45MB .sql file could be split into a shorter script :)

Comment: In window event viewer, how could i gather information to show you???
Would your please tell me???

Comment: What version of Windows are you on?  I think typing "eventvwr" in the run box, or at a command prompt, will run the event viewer on any of them. Start by expanding "Windows Logs" in the left frame, and selecting "Application".

Comment: From the windows event viewer, expand Windows Logs, then Application.  You should see the "Error" with the source of SSMS.  If you have a large number of errors, you can filter ont he right ("Filter Current Log" under "Actions") to only show Errors and Warnings

Answer (score 0):

I've had variations of this problem, where I can't save the file, especially when I've used the `undo` capability a lot, and most frequently when I've modified a script from a different development tool, while it was open in Management Studio.

Have you tried:  `save as` to another filename?  
 
(If you're concerned about losing the `undo` capability, you might try `save as` to a different filename, then do a bunch of `undo` commands and `save as` again to **another** filename... etc... until you think you've kept as many versions/steps of the undo process as you want.  Rem: a shortcut for undo is `<ctrl>-Z`, and for redo is `<ctrl>-Y`... [and you can just hold down `<ctrl>-Z` or `<ctrl>-Y` :) ], but if you type or change *anything* after undo, you lose the ability to redo.)

If you can't `save as` either, then copy/paste the code into another application (such as Notepad, or Notepad++), and SAVE IT FROM THAT APPLICATION.  (Again, if you want to simulate your undo stack, do this again after some undo commands, etc.)

But the bottom line is, I've found I have to at least CLOSE THE FILE, and reopen it, to get past these problems... sometimes exit Mgmt Studio... and then, as a bunch of old jokes about Microsoft Support go... 
You might have to restart your computer.

(P.S. I agree with Tom -- you might want to split this script into smaller scripts.)